# Parsing P2SH address from output script

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, p2sh

I have already looked at [link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92957/how-to-parse-transaction-script-to-address-the-correct-way).

I am trying to generate P2SH address from output script but no luck. I am using transaction  `40eee3ae1760e3a8532263678cdf64569e6ad06abc133af64f735e52562bccc8` for testing purpose which has one input and one output. The output goes to P2SH address that starts with 3. Output script looks like below

```
OP_HASH160
e9c3dd0c07aac76179ebc76a6c78d4d67c6c160a
OP_EQUAL
```

And destination address is `3P14159f73E4gFr7JterCCQh9QjiTjiZrG` as per open source explorers. I tried

Base58Check(e9c3dd0c07aac76179ebc76a6c78d4d67c6c160a)

Followed instructions on https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses

But could not land to the address. Can anyone help me decoding the output script to fetch address.

Comment: Did you use the correct version byte? P2SH is `05`.

Comment: Yes. I tried 1 and 5 both but didnt work

Comment: Can you post all of the steps that you did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash160 of the script is

```
e9c3dd0c07aac76179ebc76a6c78d4d67c6c160a
```

Prepend the version byte `05`

```
05e9c3dd0c07aac76179ebc76a6c78d4d67c6c160a
```

Double sha-256 gives a checksum of

```
1. 5dad64852fbff1510074011803d9bf50b9650a517240d298a07ea5c525cdc5e7
2. 7f297f3156a14d114af23b33c339817a1241afcb52a154d19683c67c538b7278
first 4 bytes: 7f297f31
```

Encoding

```
05e9c3dd0c07aac76179ebc76a6c78d4d67c6c160a7f297f31
```

as Bitcoin's Base58 gives

```
3P14159f73E4gFr7JterCCQh9QjiTjiZrG
```

By the way, that's a pretty cool address. I assume it's a vanity address, 3 P(oint) 14159 = π.